# cant create a second ingress controller using helm with custom class in Azure k8s cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have created an ingress controller using Helm with default configuration

```
default        nginx-ingress-controller        LoadBalancer   10.0.182.128   xx.xxx.xx.90     80:32485/TCP,443:31756/TCP   62m
default        nginx-ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP      10.0.12.39     <none>           80/TCP                       62m
```

using Helm:

```
helm install nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress \         
--set controller.replicaCount=2 \     
--set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
--set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
--set controller.service.loadBalancerIP="Created static IP" \
--set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-dns-label-name"="XXX-aks-ingress"
```

this ingress is running in the default namespace.

Now, I wanted to add a second ingress controller, from the official doc I have specific Ingress class

```
helm install nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress \     
--namespace ingress-nginx-devices \ #I create this namespace first 
--set controller.ingressClass="nginx-devices" \   # custom class to use for different ingress resources  
--set controller.replicaCount=2 \     
--set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
--set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
--set controller.service.loadBalancerIP="A second static Ip address created before" \
--set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-dns-label-name"="serviceIot-aks-ingress-iot"
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: ClusterRole "nginx-ingress" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-namespace" must equal "ingress-nginx-devices": current value is "default"
```

What could be wrong here ?
Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update :**

Controller-value of the controller that is processing this **ingressClass**

With recent update you might have to use the **controller.ingressClassByName**

Official doc : https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx#values

```
helm install nginx-ingress-devices stable/nginx-ingress \     
    --namespace ingress-nginx-devices \ #I create this namespace first 
    --set controller.ingressClass="nginx-devices" \   # custom class to use for different ingress resources  
    --set controller.ingressClassResource.name="nginx-devices" \
    --set controller.replicaCount=2 \     
    --set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
    --set controller.service.loadBalancerIP="A second static Ip address created before" \
    --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-dns-label-name"="serviceIot-aks-ingress-iot"
```

**Old answer**

you can try, what we are changing is name : **nginx-ingress-devices** instead of **nginx-ingress**

```
helm install nginx-ingress-devices stable/nginx-ingress \     
--namespace ingress-nginx-devices \ #I create this namespace first 
--set controller.ingressClass="nginx-devices" \   # custom class to use for different ingress resources  
--set controller.replicaCount=2 \     
--set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
--set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
--set controller.service.loadBalancerIP="A second static Ip address created before" \
--set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-dns-label-name"="serviceIot-aks-ingress-iot"
```

error you are getting is due to already there is cluster role with same name : **nginx-ingress** due to that you are getting the error.

> ClusterRoleBindings grant a user, group, or service account a
> ClusterRole’s power across the entire cluster.

You can get the reference file here : https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/nginx-ingress/templates/clusterrole.yaml

Comment: One remark is that the moment I created a clusterIssuer to get TLS certificate for the new ingress its overwrite the TLS certificate I had for the first controller, is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: i think TLS cert get stored in secret maybe ? you can change the name of secret

Comment: Yes it is but the clusterissuer has no place to store it `# k8s/cluster-issuer.yaml

apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  # name: letsencrypt-staging
  name: letsencrypt-prod-devices
spec:
  acme:
    email: xxx
    # server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      # name: letsencrypt-staging
      name: letsencrypt-prod-devices
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx-devices`

Comment: the ingress resource rules use the secret `secretName: tls-secret` but im not sure where its been created, I only use ClusterIssuer and Ingress rule

Comment: you can use the `kubectl get secrets` and check it or with respective namespace using `kubectl get secrets -n ingress-nginx-devices` clusterissuer automatic create the secret you can check it

Comment: I cant find it, tls-secret is only created for namespace default, If I create a ClusterIssuer and ingress rules in `ingress-nginx-devices` knowing that all my services are in default namespace, do I get a new tls-secret in  the namespace`ingress-nginx-devices` and also with correct routing ?

Comment: sorry not gettig, ideally you have to cluster issuer and ingress in the `namespace` in which your service is running simple. cluster issuer will create auto secret in that same namespace you can give different secret name for each ingress or cluster issuer and it will create it automatically.

Comment: I have created a separate question about this, if you can check it out  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67178086/two-tls-certificate-for-two-nginx-ingress-controller-azure-k8s-cluster] Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Nowadays the correct answer is the one provided by @hargut: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72981072/107102

Answer (score 13):

For my case the issue was with ingressclass existed already. I have simply deleted the ingresclass and it worked like a charm.

```
# kubectl get ingressclass --all-namespaces
```

This will return the name of already existing ingressclass. For my case, it was nginx. Delete that ingressclass.

```
# kubectl delete ingressclass nginx --all-namespaces
```

Verify that ingressclass is deleted

```
# kubectl get ingressclass --all-namespaces
No resources found
```

Rerun the helm update command should work.

You can also run multiple ingrss controller in parallel with new ingressClassName & ingressClassResourceName. First of all get list of all existing class name.

```
kubectl get ingressclass --all-namespaces
NAME        CONTROLLER             PARAMETERS   AGE
nginx       k8s.io/ingress-nginx   <none>       203d
```

Create a new ingress controller with unique className with this command.

```
helm install nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress \     
--namespace ingress-nginx-devices \ #I create this namespace first 
--set controller.ingressClass="nginx-devices" \   # custom class to use for different ingress resources 
--set controller.ingressClassResource.name="nginx-devices" # custom classResourceName   
--set controller.replicaCount=2 \     
--set controller.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
--set defaultBackend.nodeSelector."beta\.kubernetes\.io/os"=linux \
--set controller.service.loadBalancerIP="A second static Ip address created before" \
--set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-dns-label-name"="serviceIot-aks-ingress-iot"
```

Comment: The solution depends on what the error message is. In your case you must have got an error for ingressclass object. Nevertheless, good pointer for people who are stuck

Comment: I updated my answer to cater both use cases.

Answer (score 0):

With recent releases "controller.ingressClassResource.name" needs to get a different name when trying to deploy a second ingress.

As shown in the [list of keys](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx#values) now there's a new value that you need to set:

| Key | Type | Default | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... |  |  | ... |
| **controller.ingressClass** | string | `"nginx"` | For backwards compatibility with ingress.class annotation, use ingressClass. Algorithm is as follows, first ingressClassName is considered, if not present, controller looks for ingress.class annotation |
| controller.ingressClassByName | bool | `false` | Process IngressClass per name (additionally as per spec.controller). |
| controller.ingressClassResource.controllerValue | string | `"k8s.io/ingress-nginx"` | Controller-value of the controller that is processing this ingressClass |
| controller.ingressClassResource.default | bool | `false` | Is this the default ingressClass for the cluster |
| controller.ingressClassResource.enabled | bool | `true` | Is this ingressClass enabled or not |
| **controller.ingressClassResource.name** | string | `"nginx"` | Name of the ingressClass |

So, for example, for creating a secondary ingress for private access you can run this Helm command:

```bash
helm install nginx-ingress-private ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx \
 --create-namespace \
 --namespace ingress-private \
 --set controller.ingressClass="nginx-private" \
 --set controller.ingressClassResource.name="nginx-private" \
 --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz \
 --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-internal"="true"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).