# Two TLS certificate for two Nginx Ingress controller Azure K8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-secrets

I have two ingress controller one with default class `nginx` in `default` namespace, while the second ingress controller has a `nginx class: nginx-devices`.

Cert-manager is already installed using Helm.

I managed to get TLS certificate from Lets Encrypt for the first controller, using `ClusterIssuer` and ingress resource rules for routing `Ingress`.

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  # name: letsencrypt-staging
  name: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  acme:
    email: xx
    # server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      # name: letsencrypt-staging
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx
```

Ingress routing:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: serviceA-ingress-rules
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - FirstService.cloudapp.azure.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: FirstService.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /serviceA
        backend:
          serviceName: serviceA
          servicePort: 80
```

However, for creating the second TLS certificate for the second ingress controller, the TLS secret is not created

ClusterIssuer

```
# k8s/cluster-issuer.yaml

apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  # name: letsencrypt-staging
  name: letsencrypt-prod-devices
  namespace: ingress-nginx-devices # namespace where the second ingress controller is installed
spec:
  acme:
    email: xxx
    # server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      # name: letsencrypt-staging
      name: letsencrypt-prod-devices
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx-devices # ingress class of the second ingress controller
```

ingress routing

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: devices-ingress-rules
  namespace: default # since all the services are in default namespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-devices # ingress class of the second ingress controller
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod-devices" 
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - secondService.cloudapp.azure.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: secondService.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /serviceB
        backend:
          serviceName: serviceB
          servicePort: 80
```

by looking at the secret I can only see: `kubectl get secrets -n ingress-nginx-devices`

```
NAME                                          TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
default-token-xzp95                           kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      92m
nginx-ingress-devices-backend-token-pd4vf     kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      64m
nginx-ingress-devices-token-qvvps             kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      64m
sh.helm.release.v1.nginx-ingress-devices.v1   helm.sh/release.v1                    1      64m
```

while in default namespace:

```
tls-secret                                          kubernetes.io/tls                     2      134m
```

Why the second tls-secret is not being generated ? what could go wrong here ?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: check the second cluster issuer with server address : server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory while first one if different. Staging certificate are not mostly verified so you might be getting error of SSL/TLS cert.

Comment: Im not using any staging cert and all server addresses are the same for both cluster issuer ;)

Comment: i am sorry read the commented code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your second cluster issuer namespace is : **ingress-nginx-devices** ideally it should be in the **default** namespace as your ingress is in the **default** namespace.

Keep these three in same namespace :

1. Ingress
2. Clusterissuer
3. Service

if everything will work well you will see the secret in **default** namespace

also in your YAML of clusterissuer

```
privateKeySecretRef:
      # name: letsencrypt-staging
      name: letsencrypt-prod-devices
```

name of your secret is : **letsencrypt-prod-devices**

but in ingress it is : **tls-secret**

keep it same otherwise wont work

here sharing a full example of **clusterissuer** and **ingress** keep in the same namespace. You can change the secret name, clusterissuer name as per need. Clusterissuer will create the secret automatically just give prover names of secret & clusterissuer in ingress (matching).

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: cluster-issuer-name
  namespace: development
spec:
  acme:
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    email: harsh@example.com
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: secret-name
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx-class-name
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-class-name
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: cluster-issuer-name
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: example-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: sub.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api
        backend:
          serviceName: service-name
          servicePort: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - sub.example.com
    secretName: secret-name
```

Comment: I reproduced  the same steps, from the browser the certificate for the second ingress is generated by the` Kubernetes Ingress controller fake certificate` , while for the first ingress controller its still valid certificate from LetsEncrypt , what could be wrong here?

Comment: is it only when you have used `https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory` or still certificate is under progress and updated inside the secret. you can delete the secret, clsuterissuer, ingress and try applying again

Comment: Im not using `staging` at any place, where do you see that ?

Comment: if you have used at anyplace by mistake or certificate is not generated due to miss config of cluster issuer and ingress.

Comment: No Im not using it anywhere, Im using the same files I have shared here, let me delete secrets, clusterissuer and ingress and see what could be the output @thanks :)

Comment: dont forget to keep cluster issuer & ingress in the same namespace and secret will auto created in that namespace.

Comment: I adjust it everything to `default` name space for `ingress`, `clusterissuer` and same problem the first ingress controller got a valid certificate while the second ingress controller get fake certificate, Im not using any staging. there is only one `tls-secret` been generated at `default` namespace, does it contains both certificate ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231371/discussion-between-harsh-manvar-and-ikenahim).